# Electrostatics problems

Tags: electrostatics

In image method we use image charge to calculate field and potential at any point and we replace induced charge by image charge.But why dont we directly calculate field and potential for induced charge instead of replacing it by image charge ??

Answer (score 3):

You can't calculate it "directly" because it is not given. Rather it is the boundary condition of $V$ which is usually given. So you don't know what the induced charge distribution is in advance. If you don't want to use the image charge method, you have to solve the Poisson's equation with other methods first. Then calculate the E field, and then obtain the surface charge by $\sigma = \epsilon_0 E_\perp$.